# Make a css grid responsive,If the browser font size is changed

Tags: css

How can i make a css grid responsive when the browsers default font-size is changed.I am aware that if i define the dimensions with 'rem' it helps when the browser font-size is increased.I have created a codepen for better assesment of the problem

Here is the link for the codepen https://codepen.io/saidarshan/pen/oNbjWyb

I have wrapper div with a class called 'userpage-container'(The markup is too much to paste here.Please refer the codenpen).

The styles for the div with the class '.userpage-container' is as below:

```
   .userpage-container{
      max-width: 910px;
      height: max-content;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(12,60px);
      gap: 1rem;
    }
```

I tried using `grid-auto-rows:1fr` that did not work out.
The grid currently breaks when the font size of a browser is increased.
I will attach a screenshot of how the grid breaks now being not responsive to the font-size increase
[image]

Please refer the codepen.Styles for the '.userpage-container' is right at top.
Im very new to CSS grid and programming as a whole.Please help me out with this problem.Thank you.

Comment: instead 60px, you could use 5em/5rem or so , or even mimax() to set row size.

Comment: Ok how does the minmax work?

Comment: see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax ;)

Comment: I was wondering.If height of the wrapper matters.I have defined it has 100vh.But when i define it as 100%.The grid is responsive for font-size change in the browser

Comment: min-height instead height might be a better choice, it will allow container to grow if needed ;) height:100% requires an height set on parent so it % can be calculated.

Comment: Ya i just discovered that.I set height of body and html to 100%.So if i just use min-height instead of height.It will do the job right?

Comment: min-height:100% on body and height:100% on html should do, else min-height:100vh on body ;) if body is the container

Comment: Thank you so much for ur time and suggestion.It worked out